# how to read a file and preserve the order of lines in python beam

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

I am trying to read a file in python beam from  a GCS bucket and process it , while processing I would like to add a new field as line_number , which is the original line number that is from the file..

I tried

```py
import apache_beam as beam
from apache_beam.io import ReadFromText, WriteToText
from apache_beam.options.pipeline_options import PipelineOptions

class AddLineNumber(beam.DoFn):
    def process(self, element, line_number=beam.DoFn.ElementIndexParam):
        yield f'{line_number}: {element}'

def run_pipeline(input_file, output_file):
    pipeline_options = PipelineOptions()

    with beam.Pipeline(options=pipeline_options) as p:
        (p | 'Read from file' >> ReadFromText(input_file)
           | 'Add line numbers' >> beam.ParDo(AddLineNumber())
           | 'Write to file' >> WriteToText(output_file))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    input_file = 'input.txt'
    output_file = 'output.txt'
    run_pipeline(input_file, output_file)
```

input :

abcdefghijklmno

abdckehdehdhieh

ajhuheklolihohh

expected output:
1,abcdefghijklmno

2,abdckehdehdhieh

3,ajhuheklolihohh

Answer (score 0):

I think it is not possible to keep the original line order of the input file, because `Beam` processes the lines in parallel across one or more workers.

It's better if the information of the order is bring by the current row, example :

```
order,firstname,lastname
1,Toto,Tata
2,Lolo,Lala
```

Or with a timestamp :

```
date,firstname,lastname
2021-05-11T05:55:51,Toto,Tata
2021-05-13T07:55:51,Lolo,Lala
```

Comment: Well, using [fileio.ReadMatches](https://beam.apache.org/releases/pydoc/current/apache_beam.io.fileio.html#apache_beam.io.fileio.ReadMatches) you can read an entire file in order.

Comment: it is a valid scenario if we have a multiline json to be read by beam .@Mazlum Tosun